# Prove using first principle

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Using first principle, prove that if$$g(x) = x\cdot f(x)$$ then $$g'(x)= x \cdot f'(x) + f(x)$$

I tried this:

$$g'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{[(x+h)\cdot f(x+h) - (x\cdot f(x))]}{h}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "first principle"? Where did you use it in your attempt?

Comment: First principle is $f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$

Comment: so far so good.  Now collect the terms $\frac {x(f(x+h) - f(x)) + h(f(x+h)}{h}$ and evaluate the limit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost got it! Just readjust the terms like that

$$g'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{[(x+h)f(x+h)-xf(x)]}{h}=x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{hf(x+h)}{h}=xf'(x)+f(x)$$

Comment: Nice answer and way simpler and more direct than mine. +1

Comment: $g'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{[\color{green}{(x+h)f(x+h)}-xf(x)]}{h} = x\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\color{green}{f(x+h)}-f(x)}{h}+\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{hf(x+h)}{h}$ How does $(x+h)$ separate from $f(x+h)$

Comment: @lakada $(x+h)\cdot f(x+h) = x \cdot f(x+h) + h \cdot f(x+h)$

Comment: @dvix thanks makes sense now

Comment: $g'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{g(x+h)- g(x)}{h}
=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{[(x+h)f(x+h)-xf(x)]}{h}  = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{[x\cdot f(x+h) + h\cdot f(x+h)-xf(x)]}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{[x\cdot f(x+h)-xf(x)]}{h} + \frac{h\cdot f(x+h)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{x\cdot[ f(x+h)-f(x)]}{h} + \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{h\cdot f(x+h)}{h} = x \cdot f'(x) + f(x)$

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(x+h)-g(x)}h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(x+h)f(x+h)-xf(x)}h=$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(\color{green}x+\color{red}h)f(x+h)-\color{red}{hf(x)}+hf(x)-\color{green}{xf(x)}}h=$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\color{red}{h\left[f(x+h)-f(x)\right]}+\color{green}{x\left[f(x+h)-f(x)\right]}}h+\overbrace{f(x)}^{=\frac{hf(x)}h}=$$

$$=\lim_{h\to0}\require{cancel}\frac{\cancel h\left[f(x+h)-f(x)\right]}{\cancel h}+\lim_{h\to0}x\frac{\left[f(x+h)-f(x)\right]}h+f(x)=$$

$$=0+xf'(x)+f(x)=xf'(x)+f(x)$$

Observe that first zero is due to continuity of $\;f\;$ at each $\;x\;$ where it is differentiable

Comment: how do you get $hf(x)$ in the 2nd line?

Comment: @lakada Old trick: I added *and substracted* $\;hf(x)\;$ in the numerator. This works in several cases.

Comment: In the 3rd line how did you create those factors?

Comment: @lakada Grouping from the second line...Perhaps I'll add some colours to make it clearer.

Comment: Is there another way to solve this  question without grouping?

Comment: @lakada Of course: just as mannav showed you. His answer in fact is way simpler and direct. And if you're studying derivatives then basic algebra, as grouping and stuff, should be like multiplying $\;7\times 8\;$ for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54976/discussion-between-lakada-and-donantonio).